# How to create .vim/colors?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

How to create .vim/color directory as said on github? I am new at this. I want to know from the beginning like what to write in where (I think maybe on command prompt)
*I use windows.
** I want the solarized colorscheme

Answer (score 0):

Download `solarized.vim` file https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/raw/master/colors/solarized.vim and put it into the folder `...\Vim\vimfiles\colors\`. Then you can type `:colorscheme solarized` to activate the colorscheme.

Comment: I did. But it said no such colorscheme named 'solarized'.

Comment: Did you try Light's answer? Another option: you can put the `solarized.vim` file into the folder `...\vim80\colors\`

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, the default user level folder for runtime files is:

```
<system_driver>:\Users\<user_name>\vimfiles
```

For previous Windows versions, it might be somewhere similar to:

```
<system_driver>:\Documents And Settings\<user_name>\vimfiles
```

---

You can tell where it is on your computer by typing the following command in a vim window:

```
:set runtimepath
```

If it shows a `~`, check what it is by:

```
:echo $HOME
```

---

If it doesn't exist, create `vimfiles\colors` folder. Then put your colorscheme file in it.